# How to add text labels to trimesh scene?

Tags: trimesh

I'm trying to add text labels to objects in a Trimesh scene

The following example does not work.
My intent is to have text labels "box1", "box2" and "box3" to appear next to each created box.
However, they don't show.

```
import numpy as np
import trimesh

names = ["box1", "box2", "box3"]
angles = [np.pi/2, -np.pi/2, np.pi/4]
sizes = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
transforms = [[0., 0., 2.], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 3.0, 0.0]]

meshes = []
for n, angle, size, t in zip(names, angles, sizes, transforms):
    transform = np.array([[np.cos(angle), 0, -np.sin(angle), t[0]],
                          [0, 1, 0, t[1]],
                          [np.sin(angle), 0, np.cos(angle), t[2]],
                          [0, 0, 0, 1]])
    trm1 = trimesh.creation.box([size, size, size], transform, metadata={"name": n})
    trm2 = trimesh.path.creation.box_outline(extents=[size, size, size], transform=transform, metadata={"name": n})
    txt = trimesh.path.entities.Text(len(trm2.vertices), n, color='black')
    meshes.extend([trm1, trm2])
    meshes.append(txt)

scene = trimesh.scene.Scene(meshes)
scene.show()
```